# Как отправить по TCP соединению размер пересылаемых данных?

Tags: клиент-сервер, tcp, rust

Пытаюсь отправить с сервера клиенту данные в виде строки "ОК":

```
let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&client_stream);
...
let answer = String::from("OK");
let size_dat = answer.len();
let _ = writer.write(size_dat);// <------------ ошибка тут
let _ = writer.write(answer.as_bytes())
writer.flush().unwrap();      // <------------ проталкивание буферизованных данных в поток
```

и получаю ошибку о том что usize вовсе не byte/u8:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:87:42
   |
87 |                     let _ = writer.write(size_dat);
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^ expected &[u8], found usize
   |
   = note: expected type `&[u8]`
   = note:    found type `usize`
```

Была идея конвертировать usize в byte/u8 но не нашел такую функцию.
Может как-то через вектор их конвертировать или через String,

```
let str_size = String::from(format!("{}", size_dat));
let _ = writer.write(str_size.as_bytes());
```

Как правильно передать клиенту размер отправляемых данных?

Весь код: [Playground URL](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5a8fecac4ce69611213bf463953464fb&version=nightly&backtrace=0)  [Gist URL](https://gist.github.com/5a8fecac4ce69611213bf463953464fb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В англоязычном сегменте сайта есть ответ на ваш вопрос про конвертацию в u8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445026/converting-number-primitives-i32-f64-etc-to-byte-representations

Comment: Помогло, сделал так:
`
let answer = String::from("OK");
let size_dat = answer.len();

// превращаем размер в байты
let size: usize = size_dat;
let csize: *const usize = &size;
let bp: *const u8 = csize as *const _;
let bs: &[u8] = unsafe {
 slice::from_raw_parts(
  bp,
  mem::size_of::<usize>()
 )
};

let _ = writer.write(bs);   // шлем 8 байт размер данных.
let _ = writer.write(answer.as_bytes()); // шлем данные
writer.flush().unwrap();      // <------------ добавили проталкивание буферизованных данных в поток
`